# Use machine name instead of IP address for SSH to connect the machine

Tags: linux, ssh, ip

It is difficult to remember the IP address of different machine. Is there any way to use machine name to ssh connect the machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the Ip and machine name into `/etc/hosts` file

Like :

`machine_IP  machine_name`

`53.10.0.131    Droplet_Name`